# A question about using a hyphen

Tags: hyphens

I want to ask a question related to hyphens. Is there a hyphen between the words white and Thai in the sentence below?

- I saw a **white-Thai** temple.

Comment: No, you don't put it there. Hyphens are mainly for [*compound words/adjectives*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/hyphen).

Comment: "White-thai" (with hyphen) means white-skinned thai people. "white thai temple" (without hypen) means a thai temple which is white"

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/hyphens.asp):

> **Hyphen Rule 1:** Generally, hyphenate two or more words when they come before a noun they modify and act as a single idea. This is called a compound adjective.
>   **Examples:**
>   "an off-campus apartment"
>   "state-of-the-art design"

The two adjectives in your sentence do not act as a single idea, so they should **not** be hyphenated.

Correct: "I saw a white Thai temple."
Meaning: a temple (in Thailand or build in the Thai style) that is the color white.

---

Edit: By hyphenating "White-Thai", it communicates that these two words are part of the same idea, so it communicates two races, a person or thing that is both White and Thai. So it is possible to say "White-Thai temple", but that is a temple that was built using both cultures.